# Filtering Wordpress posts by category without reload (jquery?)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, filter, categories

I've been looking around for a way to filter my posts on http://www.waziproject.com/wazimagazine/ without reloading the page. I've had a look at jquery / json & ajax and / or a combination of these. Without avail...

The Isotope and Quicksand plugins only allow for the use of 5 categories apparently.

So my question is if anyone can help me out to turn the following into a list of filters that don't require refresh/reload of the page...

```
<div id="queryMenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="business_work">Business & Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="development_sustainability">Development & Sustainability</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="education">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="health_medecine">Health & Medecine</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="human_rights">Human Rights</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="law_order">Law & Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="media_information">Media & Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="nations">Nations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="political_economy">Political Economy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="research_innovation">Research & Innovation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="reset">All Posts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help will be exceedingly appreciated! Thanks in advance!